# Vaguely defined tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We've got a few tags which seem to me to be vague and poorly defined. They're natural phrases to use when describing a question in our field, but I don't think they're useful for tagging, categorization, and search purposes.

The offenders I'm looking at right now are:

- [technique](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) - I've [tried previously to clean this up](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230/technique-tag), but even after that I think it's just too generic a phrase to be a useful tag. In general, questions that *would* be appropriate for a [technique] tag would have other, more concrete tags to associate with.
- [writing-style](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-style) and [style](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style) have similar problems. I'm a bit more wary here, though, because I'm not sure other tags cover all the territory "writing style" does. So I'm wondering if these should be blacklisted, or just policed really really well.
- [advice](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice) - I don't think this tag conveys any information. All our answers are advice. What's this tag for? (also cf. [Is a tips tag worthwhile?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/is-a-tips-tag-worthwhile), since [tips] has been synonymed to [advice].)

What say ye?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [technique](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) seems to be well-off since your clean-up.
- [writing-style](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-style) has been merged into [style](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style) and they have been made synonyms. This is a site for writers -- we aren't going to be talking about hairstyles, architectural styles, or anything else, making "writing" in the tag a redundant space-waster.
- [advice](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice) has been deleted and blacklisted, as has [tips](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips).

Answer (score 1):

I like your clean up of [technique](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique). Leave it as it is.

[style](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style) is unnecessary. [writing-style](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-style) serves its purpose. Yes, it is generic, has a broad meaning, but that has [naming](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) in your other tag question also. Even if the meaning is broad, people know what is talked about.

[advice](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice) is a nice tag. I also suggest [help](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help), [please](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/please) and [urgent](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urgent). Ok, ok, we don't meet these problems here (yet). Just get rid of [advice](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice).